# Not able to type Letter F in vscode

Tags: reactjs, windows, visual-studio-code, frontend

I was doing react code in vscode and all of sudden faced this weird issue...I am not able to type letter F in vscode all other letters are working fine..
First I thought it is problem with my keyboard but on all other platforms it is working fine only in vscode it is not allowing me to type letter F...

Comment: I don't know if this would cause this to happen, but are any keyboard shortcuts set to just `F` ?

Comment: Also check if any of your modifier keys like Alt Ctrl Shift are stuck and being clicked

Answer (score 0):

You may have set the key 'F' for the keyboard shortcuts. Checek the keyboards shortcuts and try replacing it with another key.